# Error de git bash: /mingw64/bin/git: Argument list too long al ejecutar "git add *"

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto y estoy creando la versión inicial agregando los archivos base. El problema viene cuando intento agregar todos los archivos de la carpeta (creé previamente el archivo .gitignore con lo correspondiente) con el comando

```
git add *
```

Demora unos segundos para después mostrar el error indicado

> ```
> bash: /mingw64/bin/git: Argument list too long
> ```

Es la primera vez que me sucede y si agrego archivos de forma más especifica no sucede.

Datos de mi sistema:

- windows 7 profesional x64 service pack 1 original
- Core i5
- 4gb de ram
- git 2.16.2

La mayoria de los archivos, al menos 98% no tienen extensión, aún así usando lo siguiente da error

```
git add *.
```

Si pondo el nombre del archivo o la inicial no sucede:

```
git add O*
```

Comment: ya intentastes con con un punto en vez de un aterisco?

Comment: No lo intente debido a que tengo archivos sin extensión (en su mayoría) ya que son archivos binarios.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando haces `git add *` estás utilizando la funcionalidad de Bash llamada *expansión*, consistente en que Bash sustituye el `*` con una lista de todo aquel elemento que coincida con ese patrón. Dado que `*` coincide con cualquier cosa, al decir `git add *` lo que estás haciendo es `git add fichero1 fichero2 ... ficheroN`.

Por el motivo que sea, seguramente porque hay binarios, ese *N* es muy grande, lo que provoca que tu comando `git add fichero1 fichero2 ... ficheroN` contenga tantos elementos que exceda el límite que impone el kernel.

Para solucionarlo tienes dos opciones:

- Utilizar un bucle:

  ```
  for fichero in *
  do
      git add "$fichero"
  done
  ```
- Utiliza un patrón más restrictivo, para que expanda a un número más pequeño de elementos:

  ```
  git add directorio1/
  git add directorio2/
  git add un_patron*
  ```

Lectura recomendada: [Argument list too long error for rm, cp, mv commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18647755/1983854)

Comment: Muchas gracias, esto si me ayudo, en este caso use el for, ya que al usar patrones más restrictivos me demorare demasiado.